# Curve for a wheel moving a long a non-flat surface

Tags: differential-geometry, physics

The [cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) was the solution to a standard Freshman physics problem:

> In geometry, a **cycloid** is the curve traced by a point on a circle as it rolls along a straight line withouth slipping.  A cycloid is a specific form of trochoid and is an example of a "roulette", a curve generated by a curve rolling on another curve.

Here is the article on [rolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling) (in the sense of classical mechanics):

> The simplest case of rolling is that of rolling without slipping along a flat surface with its axis parall to the surface (or equivalently, perpendicular to the surface normal).
>
> The trajectory of any point is a trochoid; in particular, the trajectory of any point in the object axis is a line while the trajectory of any object rim is a cycloid.

Then they discuss the moment of inertia of the wheel itself.  Example, a car wheel weights 15kgs or 30lbs.

[image]

There is a parametric equation describing the curve in this case.  Vector addition yields nicely $[\text{rolling}] = [\text{translation}] + [\text{rotation}] $:

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{c} x \\ y  \end{array} \right] 
=  a \left[ \begin{array}{c} \theta \\ 1  \end{array} \right] + b \left[ \begin{array}{c}
\sin \theta \\ \cos \theta \end{array} \right] $$

What happens when the wheel is no longer on a flat surface?  Imagine driving a car or bicycle and the road isn't perfectly flat.  We might need 3D.  The response we get is quite formal:

> In the case where the rolling curve is a line and the generator is a point in the line, the roulette is called an "[involute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute)" of the of the fixed curve.

So in certain cases, we can identify the specific kind of "transform" of the curve.  We can recover $[circle] \times [line] = [trochoid] $ or possbly $[circle] \times [line] = [cycloid]$.

Let $r(t)$ be the "rolling" curve and $f(t)$ be the "fixed" curve then:

$$ t \mapsto f(t) + (p - r(t)) \frac{f'(t)}{r'(t)} $$

This formula is nearly useless, requiring the [arc-length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_curve#Length_and_natural_parametrization) parameterization of a curve. For a straight line, this is tautological. A street is nearly flat, so the surface is $1 + O(\phi(x,y))$.  The arc-lenght or surface area might be incomputable even with the calculus or algebra.

---

- [parametrization of a moving wheel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081230/parametrization-of-a-moving-wheel)
- [Rotation of a wheel in the positive direction and clockwise?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4027744/rotation-of-a-wheel-in-the-positive-direction-and-clockwise/)

Comment: The amusing related exercise is to figure out the shape of a road so that a car with square wheels can drive on it completely smoothly.

Comment: The [square wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wheel) already as a Wikipedia page.

Comment: Yes, of course, and it's an exercise in various places, too.

Comment: Re rolling one curve along another, see Exercises 8 and 10 on pp. 112-113 in [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: OK I could define $F(t) = \int_0^t  || f'(t) || \, dt $ then $f(t)$ must be $C^1$ and "integrable".  And if I'm careful the algebra itself can go around in a circle.  The attentive physics student could say something like $\dot{\omega} = ||\vec{v}||$ so the arc-length basically "maps" to the rotation of the wheel.

Comment: First, please don't use $t$ both as a dummy variable and as a limit of integration. Second, you're defining the arclength integral? If $f$ is $C^1$, then there's no problem. I don't know what you're talking about with algebra going around in a circle. If you're saying that in the general case, you cannot invert the arclength function explicitly, yes, that is definitely true. But do I need to?